# What is DefaultCertCheckMode used for?

Tags: ssl, winapi, https

The `HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_SSL_PARAM` structure defines a `DWORD` field named `DefaultCertCheckMode`. Since I have only a little background regarding SSL certificates, I would like to understand which effect that particular field has... what is a client certificate revocation check? Can I safely ignore that field when programmatically registering SSL port bindings for certain URL reservations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the process of validating a certificate, in addition to validating the signature, the date and the parent certificate, one of the things you can do is check whether the certificate has been revoked. The way you would do this is:

- Each certificate is supposed to have embedded a URL pointing to its certificate revocation list (CRL)
- You would fetch this CRL from the URL or:
- You would access a cached copy of the CRL
- You would then look for the certificate's serial number within the CRL. If found, the certificate has been revoked and must be invalidated.

With regard to [`DefaultCertCheckMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/http/ns-http-_http_service_config_ssl_param), its possible values are:

- 0: Perform the revocation check described above.
- 1: Do not perform the revocation check.
- 2: Perform the revocation check but against the cached CRL.
- 4: Perform the revocation check and use the `DefaultRevocationFreshnessTime` to refresh the cache (this indicates the number of seconds after which to check for the updated CRL).
- 0x10000: No usage check is to be performed.

It's up to you whether you want to use this setting depending on your server configuration, availability of CRLs, whether they are actually maintained etc.

Comment: is revocation check commonly performed? I imagine it mostly makes sense for clients who are validating a server's certificate?

Comment: Actually in my experience it is not commonly performed, but I don't work for any of the big boys so I can't speak for the industry. The way I see it it makes equal sense to perform the check for client certificates as well.

Comment: @mnistic Very good and enlightening answer; is that officially described somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "officially"? You mean like in some Microsoft documentation?